# I'm getting an error when hashing with JBCrypt on Android

Tags: android, encryption, hash, bcrypt, password-encryption

I'm  making some tests to hash with BCrypt, and I have the next code:

```
EditText toEnc;
Button btnEnc;
TextView encrypted;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toEnc = findViewById(R.id.toEncrypt);
    btnEnc = findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
    encrypted = findViewById(R.id.encrypted);

    btnEnc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String encrypt = BCrypt.hashpw(toEnc.getText().toString().trim(), BCrypt.gensalt(10));
            encrypted.setText(encrypt);
        }
    });

}
```

First, I had also a encryption function to generate the String to be hashed, but when I got this error I decided to try only with the String provided by the user.

Actually I've downloaded the library from maven's repository, here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt/0.4

and I added it as .jar

Now, I tried adding this dependence in build.gradle:

compile 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'

The error is generated when I do click on the button to hash the String introduced.

The application only Stops.

I'm getting the next message:

```
W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method  android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
              at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1244)
              at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:682)
              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1244)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:682)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
I/art: Thread[5,tid=4775,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb8d5a1e0,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the code inside a try-catch and It works, the problem was that the hashing process was taking more time than normal, so what I'll do is to put a ProgressDialog to avoid  the user to interact with the aplication while the hashing is in process.

I hope it to be useful for others.